# Selenium Grid - limited on running tests in parallel

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Let me describe the issue that I am currently facing:

I have setup a selenium grid with 11 VMs (1 hub and 10 nodes)

I have a test suite containing 10 tests. I am trying to run all these tests in parallel at the same time across the 10 available nodes. I am running the tests only on Chrome and so one test per node is good. I am using Gallio to run my tests in parallel.

I have setup a jenkins job to kick off my test suite. As soon as the jenkins job is kicked off, the hub gets the request and is passing them on to the nodes. There are no issues here. The only problem is, initially the hub is only sending 5 tests requests to the nodes. So, only 5 nodes are running the first 5 tests and the other 5 nodes are ideal. Only after one of the test finishes, the next test is sent to node 6. Once another test completes, the hub sends the next test to node 7 and so on.

I would ideally want all the 10 tests to be run in parallel on all the 10 available nodes. Can anyone help me here?

Here is the json config files that I am using:

hubconfig.json (I tried changing maxSession and that did not do anything)

```
{
  "host": localhost,
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 240000,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "maxSession": 5
}
```

nodeconfig.json

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "platform": "WINDOWS",
          "maxInstances": 1
        }
      ],
    "configuration":
        {
        "proxy":"org.openqa.apt.AptWebDriverProxy",
        "hubHost": localhost ,
                "hubPort":4444,
                "maxSession":5,
                "nodePolling": 2000,
        }
}
```

Comment: Try "maxSession":10 in hubconfig

Comment: Average VM (2-4 vCPU, 4-8GB RAM) can easily run node with 10 chrome browsers in parallel. I'm using one VM for hub and node and run tests from TeamCity. And "maxSession":10 for hubconfig.json will solve your issue as @Ilia mentioned. For node you can set this parameter to 1 as long as you have one instance of browser.

Comment: This worked. Thanks llia and Enot Enotovich

Comment: @Ilia I have a followup question. I have 20 VMs that I am using as nodes. In the "nodeconfig.json" file I have maxinstances set to 1 and maxSession set to 20. I am trying to understand what will happen with this setup. I am running the test only in one browser.

Comment: maxSession says how many browsers on this node can be run in parallel.
maxInstances means how many browsers of this type you can run in parallel

{ "capabilities": [ { "browserName": "chrome", "platform": "WINDOWS", "maxInstances": 1 }, { "browserName": "firefox", "platform": "WINDOWS", "maxInstances": 1 } ], "configuration": { "proxy":"org.openqa.apt.AptWebDriverProxy", "hubHost": localhost , "hubPort":4444, "maxSession":2, "nodePolling": 2000, } }
You can 2 ("maxSession":2) browsers in parallel: 1 firefox and 1 chrome. 
You cannot run 2 firefoxes or 2 chromes ("maxInstances": 1)

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2 for more details

Comment: You should mark your question as answered.